# Cannot create a virtual access point interface before starting hostapd

Tags: linux, systemd, hostapd

I have a system that I'm trying to setup as a software access point. The NIC, however, has some kind of quirk and cannot be referenced directly by hostapd, but I need to create a virtual access point interface by running this command before starting hostapd.

```
# iw dev wlp1s0 interface add uap0 type __ap
```

My initial approach was to try to setup such device with *systemd-networkd* (which is used for setup the networking), but it seems there is no way to do that.

My current approach is to create this systemd unit file

*/usr/lib/systemd/system/hostapd-pre.service*

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/iw dev wlp1s0 interface add uap0 type __ap

[Install]
WantedBy=hostapd.service
```

When my system boots up, however, it seems that the network interface does not exist, or has a different name, or for whatever reason cannot be referenced by *iw* because I get this in my journal

```
systemd[1]: Starting hostapd-pre.service...
iw[406]: command failed: No such device (-19)
systemd[1]: hostapd-pre.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=237/KEYRING
systemd[1]: hostapd-pre.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start hostapd-pre.service.
```

If however, I let the system boot, and then, after it finishes, I run the unit manually, the device is created successfully.

What do I have to do in order to successfully run the *iw* command before starting hostapd?